# xml to r data extraction

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I need to extract data from xml file and plot graphs of:
depth vs timestamp. Heading should be the IFC code. I tried using xmlToList and xmlTodataframe, but I failed doing so. I need help. My xml file looks like

```
 <document>
    <site>
       <IFC_code>HONEYCR01</IFC_code>
       <Latitude>41.960161</Latitude>
       <Longitude>-90.470759</Longitude>
       <River>Honey Creek</River>
       <Road>Hwy 136, 1st Street</Road>
       <Town>Charlotte</Town>
       <from_sensor_to_river_bottom>9.35</from_sensor_to_river_bottom>
       <Unit>foot</Unit>
    </site>
    <data>
       <value>
          <timestamp>2012-05-17 15:30:03-05</timestamp>
          <depth>8.53</depth>
       </value>
       <value>
          <timestamp>2012-05-17 14:30:06-05</timestamp>
          <depth>8.50</depth>
       </value>
       <value>
          <timestamp>2012-05-17 14:15:02-05</timestamp>
          <depth>8.51</depth>
       </value>
       <value>
          <timestamp>2012-05-17 14:00:12-05</timestamp>
          <depth>8.50</depth>
       </value>
       <value>
          <timestamp>2012-05-17 13:45:08-05</timestamp>
          <depth>8.51</depth>
       </value>
      </data>
    </document>
```

Comment: What didn't work? What error messages did you get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to work:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse("a.xml")
xmlToDataFrame(
  getNodeSet(doc, "//value"),
  colClasses=c("character","numeric")
)
```

Comment: What if I wan to draw a graph between:
from_sensor_to river_bottom  vs time ?

Comment: You have to convert your timestamps from strings to actual timestamps. If the `-05` at the end of the timestamps can be discarded, you can use `library(stringr); d$timestamp <- as.POSIXct( str_trim(d$timestamp) ); plot(depth ~ timestamp, data=d, las=1, type="b", pch=15)`.

Comment: Thank you that was of great help..
Can we do arithmatic operations like
drawing a graph between :
{( from_sensor_to river_bottom)-(depth) }VS Time
?

I must admit you are a genius !! Hats off to you

Comment: You can extract the value with `xpathSApply` and `xmlValue`:
`y <- as.numeric( xpathSApply(doc, "//from_sensor_to_river_bottom", xmlValue) );
plot(y - depth ~ timestamp, data=d, las=1, type="b", pch=15)`

Comment: That works..Thank you very much.. :) I really appreciate your help
I may post some more questions these days..
I hope you'll answer them..

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd can you please help me solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423931/extract-data-from-raw-html-in-r