# large lvl xml to r data extraction

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I need to extract data value from xml file. I tried using xmlToList and xmlTodataframe, but I failed because I receive a empty list(). I need help, because this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644998/xml-to-r-data-extraction#) is working, but it doesn't apply to my case

My xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<timeSeriesResponse xmlns="http://www.cuahsi.org/waterML/1.1/">
<queryInfo>
  <creationTime>2015-07-14T10:35:39.452+00:00</creationTime>
  <criteria MethodCalled="GetValues">
    <parameter value="S:F006875" name="site"/>
    <parameter value="S:3047695" name="variable"/>
    <parameter value="2014-08-25T00:00:00" name="startDate"/>
    <parameter value="2014-08-29T00:00:00" name="endDate"/>
  </criteria>
</queryInfo>
<timeSeries>
  <sourceInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SiteInfoType">
    <siteName>Central - Ca l'Espona (A)</siteName>
    <siteCode network="STR">F006875</siteCode>
  </sourceInfo>
  <variable>
    <variableCode default="true" vocabulary="STR">3047695</variableCode>
    <variableName>Potència T1-BOBITÈCNIC</variableName>
  </variable>
  <values>
    <value qualityControlLevelCode="0" sourceCode="1" methodCode="0" dateTimeUTC="2014-08-26T18:15:00+00:00" timeOffset="+01:00" dateTime="2014-08-26T18:15:00+00:00" censorCode="nc">452</value>
    <value qualityControlLevelCode="0" sourceCode="1" methodCode="0" dateTimeUTC="2014-08-26T18:45:00+00:00" timeOffset="+01:00" dateTime="2014-08-26T18:45:00+00:00" censorCode="nc">456</value>
    <value qualityControlLevelCode="0" sourceCode="1" methodCode="0" dateTimeUTC="2014-08-26T19:15:00+00:00" timeOffset="+01:00" dateTime="2014-08-26T19:15:00+00:00" censorCode="nc">460</value>
    <value qualityControlLevelCode="0" sourceCode="1" methodCode="0" dateTimeUTC="2014-08-27T02:30:00+00:00" timeOffset="+01:00" dateTime="2014-08-27T02:30:00+00:00" censorCode="nc">464</value>
    <value qualityControlLevelCode="0" sourceCode="1" methodCode="0" dateTimeUTC="2014-08-27T02:45:00+00:00" timeOffset="+01:00" dateTime="2014-08-27T02:45:00+00:00" censorCode="nc">460</value>
    <value qualityControlLevelCode="0" sourceCode="1" methodCode="0" dateTimeUTC="2014-08-27T03:00:00+00:00" timeOffset="+01:00" dateTime="2014-08-27T03:00:00+00:00" censorCode="nc">460</value>
    <value qualityControlLevelCode="0" sourceCode="1" methodCode="0" dateTimeUTC="2014-08-25T13:30:00+00:00" timeOffset="+01:00" dateTime="2014-08-25T13:30:00+00:00" censorCode="nc">468</value>
    <value qualityControlLevelCode="0" sourceCode="1" methodCode="0" dateTimeUTC="2014-08-25T13:45:00+00:00" timeOffset="+01:00" dateTime="2014-08-25T13:45:00+00:00" censorCode="nc">472</value>
    <qualityControlLevel qualityControlLevelID="0">
      <qualityControlLevelCode>0</qualityControlLevelCode>
      <definition>Raw data</definition>
      <explanation/>
    </qualityControlLevel>
    <method methodID="0">
      <methodCode>0</methodCode>
      <methodDescription>Not defined</methodDescription>
    </method>
  </values>
</timeSeries>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is data value? There are lots of value here? Please be specific.

Comment: @user227710 inside <values>, at the end of each <value ...>**452**</value>

Comment: You mean 452, 456, 460...472? If so, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using `rvest` package :

```
    library(rvest)
    res<-read_html("yourxmldoc.xml")
    res %>%
    html_nodes("value")%>%
    html_text()
    [1] "452" "456" "460" "464" "460" "460" "468" "472"
```